# How to make a div that appear on hover, stay while its hovered on in jquery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I have a div called title, and another one called description.
I have managed to make the div description appear while hovering on title.
here is  [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx216kzr/24/)

Now I want to make the div description stay visible while I'm hovering on it (ON THE DESCRIPTION DIV).
Once i remove the hover form the div description, it should hide.

Here is my html

```
<span class="title">Last</span>

<div class="description">some description</div>
```

Here is my JS

```
var cancel = false;
$("div.description").hide();

$(".title").hover(function () {
    cancel = (cancel) ? false : true;

    if (!cancel) {
        $("div.description").hide();
    } else if (cancel) {
        $("div.description").show();
    }
});
```

And this is the CSS

```
.title { background: red; }
.description { background: yellow; }
```

Comment: you can replace `cancel = (cancel) ? false : true;` to `cancel=!cancel`'.I know its not relevant to your question.

Comment: @bala Thanks, good improvment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not need jQuery to do this.

Given the markup you provided, just use plain CSS and utilize the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/muo4ypvc/)

```
.description {
    display: none;
}
.title:hover + .description,
.description:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

---

If you need to use jQuery, you can just include the `.description` element in your jQuery selector:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ca7fwovm/)

```
$(".title, .description").hover(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: @blex did you even look at his example? This is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @TimHallyburton Sorry, must have mistaken OP's JS Fiddle for Josh's. +1

Comment: @Josh Perfect. I always prefer to use css instead of jquery. But I'm mostly concerned with cross browser compatibility. Do you know of any compatibility issues with the adjacent sibling combinator?

Comment: @BANGO Since it's a CSS2.1 selector, there is practically full browser support - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

Comment: @Josh Works perfectly, and Thanks for the second example.